# How can I add text to a network plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am using the package `networkDynamic` to visualise two evolving networks and I would like to add, close to each network a simple legend (a few words of text). I can't find a way of doing this.

In the `networkDynamic` package, the function `render.animation` uses `plot.network` (from the package `network`) to render each frame and then compiles the different frames into an animation.

The `plot.network` arguments can be passed to `render.animation`, so the problem seems to boils down to adding text to a plot generated with `plot.network` but there doesn't seem to be a way of adding text at specified coordinates.

With a normal `plot` I would use the `text` function, but is there a way of including this function into the `plot.network` arguments?

Comment: Missing minimal working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render.animation` is a function in the `ndtv` package. You will have to create a custom `render.animation2` function based on `render.animation`. In the following function, I add an extra line to the `render.animation` function.  I add an `mtext` after each `plot.network` calls (see about 20 lines from the end). You could change it to a `text` instead of `mtext`.

```
render.animation2 <- function (net, render.par = list(tween.frames = 10, show.time = TRUE,
    show.stats = NULL, extraPlotCmds = NULL, initial.coords = 0),
    plot.par = list(bg = "white"), ani.options = list(interval = 0.1),
    render.cache = c("plot.list", "none"), verbose = TRUE, ...)
{
    if (!is.network(net)) {
        stop("render.animation requires the first argument to be a network object")
    }
    if (is.null(render.par)) {
        stop("render.animation is missing the 'render.par' argument (a list of rendering parameters).")
    }
    if (is.null(render.par$tween.frames)) {
        render.par$tween.frames <- 10
    }
    if (is.null(render.par$show.time)) {
        render.par$show.time <- TRUE
    }
    if (is.null(render.par$initial.coords)) {
        render.par$initial.coords <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = network.size(net))
    }
    if (!all(c("animation.x.active", "animation.y.active") %in%
        list.vertex.attributes(net))) {
        net <- compute.animation(net, verbose = verbose)
    }
    externalDevice <- FALSE
    doRStudioHack <- TRUE
    if (!is.null(render.par$do_RStudio_plot_hack)) {
        doRStudioHack <- render.par$do_RStudio_plot_hack
    }
    if (!is.function(options()$device)) {
        if (names(dev.cur()) == "RStudioGD" & doRStudioHack) {
            message("RStudio's graphics device is not well supported by ndtv, attempting to open another type of plot window")
            if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
                windows()
            }
            else if (length(grep(R.version$platform, pattern = "apple")) >
                0) {
                quartz()
            }
            else {
                x11()
            }
            externalDevice <- TRUE
        }
    }
    if (par("bg") == "transparent" & is.null(plot.par$bg)) {
        plot.par$bg <- "white"
    }
    origPar <- par(plot.par)
    oopts <- ani.options(ani.options)
    slice.par <- get.network.attribute(net, "slice.par")
    if (is.null(slice.par)) {
        stop("render.animation can not locate the 'slice.par' list of parameters in the input network object")
    }
    render.cache <- match.arg(render.cache)
    plot_params <- list(...)
    if (is.null(plot_params$label)) {
        plot_params$label <- function(slice) {
            network.vertex.names(slice)
        }
    }
    if (is.null(plot_params$xlab) & render.par$show.time) {
        plot_params$xlab <- function(onset, terminus) {
            ifelse(onset == terminus, paste("t=", onset, sep = ""),
                paste("t=", onset, "-", terminus, sep = ""))
        }
    }
    if (!is.null(render.par$show.stats) && render.par$show.stats !=
        FALSE) {
        if (render.par$show.time) {
            plot_params$xlab <- eval(parse(text = paste("function(slice,onset,terminus){stats<-summary.statistics.network(slice",
                render.par$show.stats, ")\n return(paste('t=',onset,'-',terminus,' ',paste(rbind(names(stats),stats),collapse=':'),sep='')) }",
                sep = "")))
        }
        else {
            plot_params$xlab <- eval(parse(text = paste("function(slice){stats<-summary.statistics.network(slice",
                render.par$show.stats, ")\n return(paste(rbind(names(stats),stats),collapse=':')) }",
                sep = "")))
        }
    }
    if (is.null(plot_params$jitter)) {
        plot_params$jitter <- FALSE
    }
    interp.fun <- coord.interp.smoothstep
    starts <- seq(from = slice.par$start, to = slice.par$end,
        by = slice.par$interval)
    ends <- seq(from = slice.par$start + slice.par$aggregate.dur,
        to = slice.par$end + slice.par$aggregate.dur, by = slice.par$interval)
    xmin <- aggregate.vertex.attribute.active(net, "animation.x",
        min)
    xmax <- aggregate.vertex.attribute.active(net, "animation.x",
        max)
    ymin <- aggregate.vertex.attribute.active(net, "animation.y",
        min)
    ymax <- aggregate.vertex.attribute.active(net, "animation.y",
        max)
    if (is.null(plot_params$xlim)) {
        if (xmin == xmax) {
            xmax <- xmin + 1
            xmin <- xmin - 1
        }
        plot_params$xlim <- c(xmin, xmax)
    }
    if (is.null(plot_params$ylim)) {
        if (ymin == ymax) {
            ymax <- ymin + 1
            ymin <- ymin - 1
        }
        plot_params$ylim <- c(ymin, ymax)
    }
    if (is.numeric(render.par$initial.coords)) {
        coords <- matrix(render.par$initial.coords, ncol = 2,
            nrow = network.size(net))
    }
    slice <- network.collapse(net, starts[1], ends[1], rule = slice.par$rule,
        rm.time.info = FALSE)
    activev <- is.active(net, starts[1], ends[1], v = seq_len(network.size(net)),
        rule = if (slice.par$rule != "all") {
            "any"
        })
    if (length(slice) > 0 & network.size(slice) > 0) {
        coords[activev, 1] <- get.vertex.attribute(slice, "animation.x")
        coords[activev, 2] <- get.vertex.attribute(slice, "animation.y")
    }
    coords2 <- coords
    if (render.cache == "plot.list") {
        ani.record(reset = TRUE)
    }
    for (s in 1:length(starts)) {
        if (verbose) {
            print(paste("rendering", render.par$tween.frames,
                "frames for slice", s - 1))
        }
        slice <- network.collapse(net, starts[s], ends[s], rule = slice.par$rule,
            rm.time.info = FALSE)
        activev <- is.active(net, starts[s], ends[s], v = seq_len(network.size(net)),
            rule = if (slice.par$rule != "all") {
                "any"
            })
        if (length(slice) > 0 & network.size(slice) > 0) {
            evald_params <- .evaluate_plot_params(plot_params = plot_params,
                net = net, slice = slice, s = s, onset = starts[s],
                terminus = ends[s])
            for (t in 1:render.par$tween.frames) {
                coords2[activev, 1] <- get.vertex.attribute(slice,
                  "animation.x")
                coords2[activev, 2] <- get.vertex.attribute(slice,
                  "animation.y")
                tweenCoords <- interp.fun(coords, coords2, t,
                  render.par$tween.frames)
                plot_args <- list(x = slice, coord = tweenCoords[activev,
                  , drop = FALSE])
                plot_args <- c(plot_args, evald_params)
                do.call(plot.network, plot_args)
                mtext("my text\n on two lines", side = 3) #my.legend
                if (!is.null(render.par$extraPlotCmds)) {
                  eval(render.par$extraPlotCmds)
                }
                if (render.cache == "plot.list") {
                  ani.record()
                }
            }
            coords <- coords2
        }
        else {
            evald_params <- .evaluate_plot_params(plot_params = plot_params,
                net = net, slice = slice, s = s, onset = starts[s],
                terminus = ends[s])
            if (render.par$show.time) {
                xlab <- evald_params$xlab
            }
            else {
                xlab <- NULL
            }
            singlenet <- network.initialize(1)
            for (t in 1:render.par$tween.frames) {
                plot.network(singlenet, vertex.cex = 0, xlab = xlab)
                if (!is.null(render.par$extraPlotCmds)) {
                  eval(render.par$extraPlotCmds)
                }
                if (render.cache == "plot.list") {
                  ani.record()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    par(origPar)
    if (externalDevice) {
        dev.off()
    }
}
```

It is then important to assign your new function `render.animation2` to the `ndtv` namespace. If you don't, it will crash because `render.animation` refers to functions that can only be found in its own namespace.

```
environment(render.animation2) <- asNamespace('ndtv')
environment(render.animation)  #<environment: namespace:ndtv>
environment(render.animation2) #<environment: namespace:ndtv>
```

Using, `render.animation2`, you will then get your legend printed on each slide of the animation.

```
require(ndtv)
triangle <- network.initialize(3) # create a toy network
add.edge(triangle,1,2)
# add an edge between vertices 1 and 2
add.edge(triangle,2,3)
# add a more edges
activate.edges(triangle,at=1) # turn on all edges at time 1 only
activate.edges(triangle,onset=2, terminus=3,
e=get.edgeIDs(triangle,v=1,alter=2))
add.edges.active(triangle,onset=4, length=2,tail=3,head=1)
render.animation2(triangle) #custom function
ani.replay()
```

Here's what the last slide looks like in the animation: 
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! it's perfect!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Don't forget to upvote (upward gray triangle) and accept the answer (green checkmark). Merci.

Comment: not necessary to re-write the entire command and hack the ndtv namespace just to add text, the regular plot arguments are supported

Comment: OP specifically asked for a `text` function, which is not a `plot` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to add a few lines of text, you can pass the standard plot arguments `main` (for the main title) or `xlab` (for the x-axis caption). you can separate lines with the newline escape "\n"

```
library(ndtv)
data(short.stergm.sim)
render.animation(short.stergm.sim,main='hello\nworld')
```

It is also possible to plot other graphic elements (such as `legend` or `text` or maps) using the `extraPlotCmds` argument to `render.animation`.   For example, if you wanted to plot "hello world" in blue at coordiantes 0,0 using `text` you can wrap it in an `expression` and pass it in via `render.par`

```
render.animation(short.stergm.sim,
                 render.par=list(extraPlotCmds=expression(
                                   text(0,0,'hello\nworld',col='blue')
                                ))
                 )
```

the extra plot command will evaluated on each frame as the network is rendered

Comment: Hi Skye, unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. My question is about putting several text boxes at an exact location in the plot, so that should be something like: render.animation(short.stergm.sim,text(-6,10,"Discussion groups",cex = 1)). It would be great to know if you have a way of doing this without changing the command. As far as I can see the "regular plot argument" doesn't do. Thanks.

Comment: I assume that you have downvoted my perfectly good answer. OP specifically asked for a `text` function, which is not a `plot` argument. `Plot` arguments are everything that is `plot()`. Have you tried to add a `text` function in `extraPlotCmds`?

Comment: Updated my answer to demonstrate use of `text` via extraPlotCmds. It seems to work fine.